# The console doesn't know what the error is—maybe it’s because the onclick() method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The console is totally empty—I can’t find the error. I found this code in a video tutorial and in the video it’s working fine.

Here is my simple code:

```js
function addItem() {
  inames = []
  iqtyp = []
  iprice = []
  inames.push(document.getElementById('pname').value);
  iqtyp.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('pqty').value));
  iprice.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value));

  displayCart();
}

function displayCart() {
  cartdata = '<table><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th></tr>';

  total = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < inames.length; i++) {
    total += iqtyp[i] * iprice[i]
    cartdata += "<tr><td>" + inames[i] + "</td><td>" + iqtyp[i] + "</td><td>" + iprice[i] + "</td><td>" + iqtyp[i] * iprice[i] + "</td><td><button onclick='delElement(" + i + ")' >Delete</button></td></tr>"
  }

  cartdata += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>' + total + '</td></tr></table>'

  document.getElementById('cart').innerHTL = cartdata;
}

function delElement(a) {
  inames.splice(a, 1);
  iqtyp.splice(a, 1)
  iprice.splice(a, 1)
  displayCart()
}
```

```css
#frm {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#cart {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: -100;
}

th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title> Cinematic </title>
  <script src="shoppingcart.js"></script>
  <link href="shoppingcart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id='frm'>
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <input id='pname' type='text'><br>
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input id='pqty' type='number'><br>
    <label>Unit Price</label>
    <input id='price' type='number'><br>
    <button onclick="addItem()"> Add Item </button>
  </div>

  <div id='cart'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

The console doesn’t give anything out.

Comment: "_The console is totally empty_" Because nothing in your code is attempting to write to the console. What line of code were you expecting to print something to the console and why?

Comment: Like @csm_dev said unless you use `console.log()` JS will not tell you what's wrong

Comment: no, I mean there is no error in the console but it is not working...

Comment: After you click on the button, it should write everything down - like in a shopping cart. For example: 
Product: iPhone 6
quantity: 2
Price: 500
total: 1000

Comment: It's a typo look the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo you didn't write `HTML` properly when you use `.innerHTML` on the last line of `displayCart()`

```js
function addItem() {
  inames = []
  iqtyp = []
  iprice = []
  inames.push(document.getElementById('pname').value);
  iqtyp.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('pqty').value));
  iprice.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value));

  displayCart();
}

function displayCart() {
  cartdata = '<table><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th></tr>';

  total = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < inames.length; i++) {
    total += iqtyp[i] * iprice[i]
    cartdata += "<tr><td>" + inames[i] + "</td><td>" + iqtyp[i] + "</td><td>" + iprice[i] + "</td><td>" + iqtyp[i] * iprice[i] + "</td><td><button onclick='delElement(" + i + ")' >Delete</button></td></tr>"
  }

  cartdata += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>' + total + '</td></tr></table>'

  document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = cartdata;
}

function delElement(a) {
  inames.splice(a, 1);
  iqtyp.splice(a, 1)
  iprice.splice(a, 1)
  displayCart()
}
```

```css
#frm {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#cart {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: -100;
}

th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id='frm'>
  <label>Product Name</label>
  <input id='pname' type='text'><br>
  <label>Quantity</label>
  <input id='pqty' type='number'><br>
  <label>Unit Price</label>
  <input id='price' type='number'><br>
  <button onclick="addItem()"> Add Item </button>
</div>

<div id='cart'></div>
```

Comment: thank you! now I feel kinda dumb to bother you all with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line in Code

```
document.getElementById('cart').innerHTL = cartdata;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = cartdata;
```

there is nothing like innerHTL

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your displayCart function. you didn't spell the HTML correctly it should be

```
document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = cartdata;
```